# Filter multiple value from multi array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My array like this :

```
$myArray = array(
    array(
        'uid' => '100',
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'pic_square' => 'urs121'
    ),
    array(
        'uid' => '200',
        'name' => 'machavent',
        'pic_square' => 'urs222'
    ),
    array(
        'uid' => '300',
        'name' => 'Ayem',
        'pic_square' => 'urs333'
    ),
    array(
        'uid' => '400',
        'name' => 'Bucin',
        'pic_square' => 'urs444'
    ),
    array(
        'uid' => '500',
        'name' => 'Bangcad',
        'pic_square' => 'urs555'
    )
);
```

this my function :

```
function filterElement($array, $key, $value){
    foreach($array as $subKey => $subArray){
        if($subArray[$key] != $value){
            unset($array[$subKey]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

this working fine if I just need get data from uid=100

```
$mydata = '100';
$array = filterElement($myArray, "uid", $mydata);
```

my results

[image: my results]

But how if I want to get data from uid = [100,300] ?

I'm trying to call like this

```
$mydata = ['100','300'];
$array = filterElement($myArray, "uid", $mydata);
```

and change my function to

```
function filterElement($array, $key, $value){
    foreach($array as $subKey => $subArray){
        for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++){
            if($subArray[$key] != $value[$i]){
                unset($array[$subKey]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

and the results is

```
array(0) {
}
```

so my problem is how to filter data using multi value from multi dimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_filter` function:

```php
function filterElement($array, $key, $value){
    if (!is_array($value)) $value = [$value];
    return array_filter($array, function($item) use ($key, $value){
        return in_array($item[$key], $value);
    });
}

// Usage:
$array = filterElement($myArray, "uid", '100');
$array = filterElement($myArray, "uid", ['100', '300']);
```